# Library or some code for building live stream server on esp32

Tags: stream, rtsp, esp32, esp-idf

My project is about to develop a mini live stream server on esp32 (wrover) using esp-idf library, and any computer has wifi connection to my esp can listen voice recorded from Mic lay on esp32. I wonder if have any library to build live stream sever? I found gstream lib but it is only support linux base or mobile. Can I use curl lib to build simple rtsp stream?
Another way: may I try to send data recorded from my esp32 to intermediate computer which stand as rtsp server?

Toclarify, about my project:
Voice -> vs1053 codec -> esp32 -> computer -> human listening

Comment: Edit: esp32 wroom